# PowerShell Is there a way to get proper order of properties in Select-Object so that each object has order?

Tags: powershell

Following code lists all AD users.

```
$Domain.DomainUsersFullList = Get-ADUser -Server $Domain -ResultPageSize 500000 -Filter * -Properties *, "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select * -ExcludeProperty *Certificate, PropertyNames, *Properties, PropertyCount, Certificates
$($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[0]).PSObject.Properties.Name[12]
$($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[10]).PSObject.Properties.Name[12]
```

It seems that order returned by `PSObject.Properties.Name` can be different. Is there a way to order properties without exclusively telling `Select-Object` the order you want them in?

Just for the sake of why I need this:

- https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteWord - I wrote a function `Add-WordTable` that takes any `$Object` and puts this into Word document. No need to parse objects yourself. Just pass it to function and it will be put into Word document.

I am now working on same thing for:

- https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteExcel - which has function `Add-ExcelWorksheetData` that does exactly the same as above with one exception .. since it's Excel you don't have column limit. So with 100 columns I was/am getting wrong order per each row. Which makes no sense.

While in case of WORD document I didn't notice this issue because I never added more then 10 columns, with Excel and 100 columns I was getting wrong order. Below is an example of this:

[image]

Here is the method that does the conversion:

```
function Format-PSTableConvertType2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        $Object,
        [switch] $SkipTitles,
        [string[]] $ExcludeProperty,
        [switch] $NoAliasOrScriptProperties,
        [switch] $DisplayPropertySet
    )
    [int] $Run = 0
    $Array = New-ArrayList
    $Titles = New-ArrayList
    if ($NoAliasOrScriptProperties) {$PropertyType = 'AliasProperty', 'ScriptProperty'  } else {$PropertyType = ''}
    Write-Verbose "Format-PSTableConvertType2 - Option 2 - NoAliasOrScriptProperties: $NoAliasOrScriptProperties"

    foreach ($O in $Object) {
        $ArrayValues = New-ArrayList
        if ($DisplayPropertySet -and $O.psStandardmembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames) {
            $ObjectProperties = $O.psStandardmembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames.Where( { $ExcludeProperty -notcontains $_  } ) #.Name
        } else {
            $ObjectProperties = $O.PSObject.Properties.Where( { $PropertyType -notcontains $_.MemberType -and $ExcludeProperty -notcontains $_.Name  } ).Name
        }
        #$ObjectProperties = $O.PSObject.Properties
        foreach ($Name in $ObjectProperties) {
            if ($Run -eq 0 -and -not $SkipTitle) { Add-ToArray -List $Titles -Element $Name }
            Add-ToArray -List $ArrayValues -Element $O.$Name
        }
        if ($Run -eq 0 -and -not $SkipTitle) {Add-ToArray -List ($Array) -Element $Titles }
        Add-ToArray -List $Array -Element $ArrayValues
        $Run++
    }

    return , $Array
}
```

It essentially converts object into Array of Arrays. Which then makes it trivial to just loop thru rows / columns.

Now it's important that while generally I could probably make Get-AdUser display only values I want in proper order I am working on general use modules (PSWriteWord/PSWriteExcel) and I want people to pass any object to it and not have to care about it too much.

Comment: What is the 'proper' order for properties?  I assume that depends on what you're trying to do.  What is your overall goal?  Maybe there is an easier/better way to achieve it - at the moment, this sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well the problem I'm getting is that if you ask first object the order will be different then the last one. Which if you try to put it into Word or Excel will make sure headers will be a mess. I would expect that 1st and 12th object have consistent order.

Comment: Why would the order matter in the first place? You should access properties by name, not by index. If you want to use exported user data in Word or Excel: export the data as CSV.

Comment: Well what I do is I get $Domain>DomainUsersFullList i then loop thru it. One by one. Since I don't the object I scan all available properties with PSObject.Properties.Name. and then I start putting that to excel/word. Each next object in $Domain.DomainUsesFullList is going thru that .. but then on larger objects (100 columns) I get different order of properties and that means header I have created isn't good anymore. I can probably work it around by saving 1st properties order and apply that properties order to next objects but thought there may be a better way.

Comment: I don't want to use CSV. I wrote powershell module that converts any Object into Excel Worksheet exporting data straight to excel. Wouldn't make much sense to add csv to it right?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. What version of PowerShell are you using? I am not clear on _how_ this affects later code. How do you loop through the collection? When you use something like [Export-Excel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/1.90/Content/Export-Excel.ps10). Why do you need to access the property names by index? Also calling `-Properties *` is super slow. Why do you need almost all of them?

Comment: I am on Windows 10 insiders. So newest powershell. You can take a look at my answer which shows the output. I'm writting alternative to Export-Excel as it doesn't support all object types and I would say it has same order issue as far as I know.

Comment: @Matt As for all of them.. well I created this PSWinDocumentation project (https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWinDocumentation) which essentially creates AD documentation for you. In new version it will export everything to Excel as well. In old version some functions were using pipelined objects (think get-aduser and Managers email for that user). So what I do now is get all properties at once. And then based on that total list I use properties on demand. While I don't necessary need that in order for that I thought I would give people an option to export whole list to excel..

Comment: @Matt I just checked Export-Excel and they address this by using first header.             foreach ($Name in $script:Header) { try   {Add-CellValue -TargetCell $ws.Cells[$Row, $ColumnIndex] -CellValue $TargetData.$Name} so essentially doing what I proposed in my answer.

Comment: I think your question still leaves a big gap of understanding with what you truly want but given what you are trying to do I just do stuff like this: `$header = $data[0].psobject.properties.name` then you would loop twice. First over the collection then over each property in turn. As long as the first object best represents the collection then null and missing properties can be silently ignored.

Comment: I would just loop once for headers and then subsequently for other rows. So 1st row may get double loop but rest will be just once. $Headers = $Data[0].PsObject.Properties.Name  and then Select-Object $Headers which will solve my problem. I can't ignore null/missing properties as I don't know that based on 1st object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless anyone has a better option:

```
$SpecialData = $Domain.DomainUsersFullList | Select-Object $($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[0]).PSObject.Properties.Name

$($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[0]).PSObject.Properties.Name[12]
$($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[10]).PSObject.Properties.Name[12]
$($SpecialData[0] | Select-Object $($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[0]).PSObject.Properties.Name).PSObject.Properties.Name[12]
$($SpecialData[10] | Select-Object $($Domain.DomainUsersFullList[0]).PSObject.Properties.Name).PSObject.Properties.Name[12]
```

Basically what this does is copy the order of 1st element and applies same order to each and every new line. This ensures that each object will return properties in same order as 1st element.

Final implementation:

```
function Format-PSTableConvertType2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        $Object,
        [switch] $SkipTitles,
        [string[]] $ExcludeProperty,
        [switch] $NoAliasOrScriptProperties,
        [switch] $DisplayPropertySet,
        $OverwriteHeaders
    )
    #[int] $Run = 0
    $Array = New-ArrayList
    $Titles = New-ArrayList
    if ($NoAliasOrScriptProperties) {$PropertyType = 'AliasProperty', 'ScriptProperty'  } else {$PropertyType = ''}
    Write-Verbose "Format-PSTableConvertType2 - Option 2 - NoAliasOrScriptProperties: $NoAliasOrScriptProperties"

    # Get Titles first (to make sure order is correct for all rows)
    if ($OverwriteHeaders) {
        $Titles = $OverwriteHeaders
    } else {
        foreach ($O in $Object) {
            if ($DisplayPropertySet -and $O.psStandardmembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames) {
                $ObjectProperties = $O.psStandardmembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames.Where( { $ExcludeProperty -notcontains $_  } ) #.Name
            } else {
                $ObjectProperties = $O.PSObject.Properties.Where( { $PropertyType -notcontains $_.MemberType -and $ExcludeProperty -notcontains $_.Name  } ).Name
            }
            foreach ($Name in $ObjectProperties) {
                Add-ToArray -List $Titles -Element $Name
            }
            break
        }
        # Add Titles to Array (if not -SkipTitles)
        if (-not $SkipTitle) {
            Add-ToArray -List $Array -Element $Titles
        }
    }
    # Extract data (based on Title)
    foreach ($O in $Object) {
        $ArrayValues = New-ArrayList
        foreach ($Name in $Titles) {
            Add-ToArray -List $ArrayValues -Element $O.$Name
        }
        Add-ToArray -List $Array -Element $ArrayValues
    }
    return , $Array
}
```